# HTML display=none doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html

My code:

```php
<?php
  if($counter==0) {
    echo "value of counter = $counter"
  ?>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById("tt").style.display = "none";
  </script>
  <?php
  }
?>
<html>
<body>
  <form action="new_upload.php" method="post" name="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formform">
    <input type='submit' value='Go Back!' name="sbmt" id="tt"
      <?php if($counter==0) { ?> display="none" <?php } ?> />
  </form>
  <p> Submit a different file by clicking the back button in case your file was unable to upload.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see I have tried to set the property display=none of the submit button through
1) if php condition is true, I added javascript.
2) I added php in my form submit button code.
but it is not working both ways. I can see through the print statement that the value of counter is 0 but then also it is visible.

Answer (score 2):

You are executing the script before the element is created. Move the code below the element to work

Comment: but then how would I be able to access the value of counter?? my counter remains 0 if file is uploaded properly

Comment: @user8814349, easy, you render html for the form including "tt" and then if counter is 0 add javascript block with display none for "tt".

Comment: Remember that the php code executes in the server, and it executes before the html and javascript that you are generating and sending to the client. After that, the client executes the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such attribute as `display`, you need to use `style="display: none"` instead.

Comment: your solution is working but it should also work because of the javascript I added. any reason for that?